# Returning previous and current index sum while mapping through array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array such as this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  amount: 100
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  amount: -50
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  amount: 30
 }
]
```

How can I retrieve an array where the amount would be the sum of the previous index sum?
For example if the starting amount is 0, I would like to retrieve this array:

```
[100, 50, 80] // 0 + 100 = 100, then 100 - 50 = 50, then 50 + 30 = 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use accumulator param from the `reduce` with `index - 1` to get the latest value added.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"amount":100},{"id":2,"amount":-50},{"id":3,"amount":30}]

const result = data.reduce((r, { amount }, i) => {
  r.push((r[i - 1] || 0) + amount)
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `map` and `thisArg` argument.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"amount":100},{"id":2,"amount":-50},{"id":3,"amount":30}]

const result = data.map(function({ amount }, i) {
  return (this.last = (this.last || 0) + amount)
}, {})

console.log(result)
```